# Apply masterpage to multiple site collections

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I need to apply a masterpage to multiple site collections in SharePoint 2010. The masterpage is part of a feature of a VS 2010 solution. The problem is, I can only use site and web scope, not web application. When I use the following code, I get an error that an .aspx website could not be found. Does anybody have a hint why?

```
SPWeb CurrentWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

string masterUrl = CurrentWeb.MasterUrl = CurrentWeb.Site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + customMasterpage;

string customUrl = CurrentWeb.CustomMasterUrl = CurrentWeb.Site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + customMasterpage;

CurrentWeb.Update();

SPWebApplication webApp = CurrentWeb.Site.WebApplication;
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
foreach (SPSite site in webApp.Sites)
{
     foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
     {
          ChangeMasterPage(web, masterUrl, customUrl);
     }
}
```

Comment: refer : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/060d29b2-1233-4176-bb2b-f69b978d9c03/master-page-for-multiple-site-collection  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/can-i-use-the-same-master-page-between-site-collections  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/can-i-use-the-same-master-page-between-site-collections

Comment: I can't use the first example as I need to deploy this through VS2010,  the second and third links I have already tried to no avail

Comment: how are you deploying now WSP?, You can make the feature deployment via VS or WSP

Comment: basically, what I need to do, is deploy AND apply a masterpage from code behind of a feature event receiver that initially deploys everything to a SPWeb contained within the web application.